# Mouse Click function in OpenCV using C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am relatively new to OpenCV and I am trying to work on virtual mouse. I figured out how to detect different colors and filter them out. I couldn't find how to make mouse click when specific color is detected. Here my sample code:

```
if (b == 1){
        if (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && PosX >= 0 && PosY >= 0)

        //Here is the function to left clicking the mouse

    }
```

I figured out how to move the mouse. I used `SetCursorPos(x,y)`. I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mouse click event comes with the x,y of the mouse position. Use these coordinates for accessing the image.
Take a look at [`SetMouseCallback()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#setmousecallback).
[Here's](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/ffilldemo.cpp) an example of how to use it.

Comment: But is there a special function to do that. For example to move the mouse there is `SetCursorPos(x,y)` but what is the function for the click event?

Comment: Thank you @Adi, now I get the whole idea of handling mouse click event.